# jQuery .before() with external HTML file (same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the .before() function in jQuery to load an external html file in the same domain.

What I'd like is an HTML form with dynamically placed form elements based on users' entries (being able to add as many phone number fields as they want for instance). I tried many options like .load() or .html() but I can't seem to find any working solution. Maybe I'm not doing this right...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_society_number").click(function(){
            $(this).closest('table').before(forms/society_phone_number.html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

What should I use instead of "forms/society_phone_number.html"?

I'll have many pages with shared forms, that's why I want them in external files.

Another reason why I'd like to load external HTML files is that when using .before() function, I have to use "\" for each line breaks in my code...

Thank you :)

Comment: What you want is `.load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `$.ajax` or one of it's helper methods to get the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_society_number").click(function(){
        var self = this;
        $.get("forms/society_phone_number.html",function(response){
            $(self).closest('table').before(response);
        });            
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I wonder why I got a down vote on my question though... I searched a lot with no result... Anyway, it's working like a charm now, thank you!!

Comment: you have to *show* that you did research, for example showing ways that you tried to solve it on your own that didn't work. Obviously `.before("thepath")` won't work because `.before` doesn't do ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .load('/url/to/script')

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_society_number").click(function(){
            $(this).closest('table tbody').load('forms/society_phone_number.html');
        });
    });
</script>
```